# Outline on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<a href="main.html" class="admin"><div class="buttonlabel">Admin</div></a>
```

and CSS

```
a.admin  
{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
background: transparent url(./images/adminnormal.png?rand=628) no-repeat top center;
height:75px;
width:75px;
margin:5px;
outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;
}
```

The code above has this output:

[image]

I want this link to be outlined only when a user clicks it (`onclick`). Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Consider that you shouldn't hav a block element (here: div) in an link. This isn't valid HTML.

Comment: advice don't put a block element inside an inline element. So, you can use span instead of div.

Comment: Judging by the various answers below, there needs to be some clarification of the duration of the dotted border. Is it just while the mouse button is down, is it until another link is clicked, etc. I suspect that simply setting a style in the onclick handler (As per Arthur Halma's post) would suffice, because the target page will be loaded shortly afterwards, and the  page containing the link will disappear.

Comment: @belugabob: you are right, but check the @Kris question: "I want this link to be outlined only when a user clicks it (onclick). Any ideas how to do that?", so my answer was a solution to this problem, I have no idea about future logic of whole webpage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<a href="main.html" class="admin"><div class="buttonlabel">Admin</div></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.admin  
{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
background: transparent url(./images/adminnormal.png?rand=628) no-repeat top center;
height:75px;
width:75px;
margin:5px;

}
a.admin.act{outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.admin').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('act');
})
```

Comment: Wow this works for me, thanks a lot to all of you guys for your responses! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple buddy:

```
$('a.admin').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('style','outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:active`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) pseudo-class:

```
a.admin:active {
  outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;
}
```

No need for any javascript at all.

EDIT: It is pointed out that `:active` is defined to only work while the mouse is held down. The `:focus` pseudo-class can be used - it will be active when the link is focused, which it will be after being clicked until something else is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gareth, is this cross browser compatible?

Comment: Nice one. Aditionally note that the `active` pseudoclass doesn't work in IE7.

Comment: Note that this *probably* isn't what he wants. "The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, *between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.*"

Comment: @Kris - Yes! [even in IE](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css?IE6=on&IE7=on&IE8=on&FX2=on&FX3=on&OP9=on&uas=CUSTOM#css2pseudoclasses)

Comment: Unfortunately the `focus` pseudoclass is even less supported in IE 7 (even 8) than the `active` pseudoclass :( otherwise this could be a good solution.

Comment: In my opinion, outlines-on-click are never crucial functionality. So I wouldn't mind too much about older versions of IE not displaying them, not enough to resort to javascript which *all* browsers then have to use rather than the simple available solution. Of course, YMMV but I'm sure there are bigger problems to worry about